# Can I convert camera rotation to sphere mesh rotation?

Tags: three.js

I have a very large `SphereBufferGeometry` that I project an equirectangular 360 image onto in order to create a 360 scene. I have two functions to my application: 1.) to set the initial view of which part of the scene should be viewed at scene load and 2.) to always load the scene at that saved coordinates.

**To set the initial view of which part of the scene should be viewed at scene load:**
I can use `OrbitControls` to move the camera to look at a certain direction of this sphere, and I can save the `position` of the camera when I look at a 360 scene position I like.

**To always load the scene at that saved coordinates:**
I can set the position of the camera to this previously saved `position` and view the scene at my favorite starting location.

This works well, but I do not want to set camera position each time a 360 scene loads. Rather, my requirement is to load the scene with camera in a neutral position, and rather the sphere `mesh` is rotated on the sphere such that I am looking at the [x,y,z] position of my favorite position set earlier.

Is it at all possible to take a camera `position` and `rotation` and use those values to `rotate` or `position` a mesh on my sphere?

Can I use `OrbitControls` to rotate the entire scene/sphere instead of the camera onClick?

Comment: What do you mean you save the camera's `position`? It sounds like you should be saving the `rotation`. Do you mean you save the position to then do `camera.lookAt(position)`?

Comment: @Marquizzo >Do you mean you save the position to then do camera.lookAt(position)? 
Yes, thats exactly right.

Comment: @ClaytonRothschild Then forget `OrbitControls`, keep the camera fixed at ( 0, 0, 1 ), and rotate the sphere with the mouse, instead. Set `sphere.rotation.order = 'YXZ'`. On mouse move, do `sphere.rotation.set( pitch_in_radians, heading_in_radians, 0 )`. Pitch should be in [ - pi / 2, pi / 2 ]; heading can be anything. Save the sphere rotation. Camera never moves..